# create 1 update button for all value

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, arrays

I'm still learning about php and I have this script that I need to modify. In this script there are multiple update buttons and I want to create another button to update all the values.

this is the script I have

```
<div class='tableContainer'>
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <th width='100px'>Pasaran</th>                          
                            <th width='150px'>Status</th>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <?php foreach($pasaran as $b){ ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td width='101px'><?php echo $b['keterangan']; ?></td>
                                <td width='151px'>
                                    <form action='<?php echo base_url('home/update_pasaran'); ?>' method='POST' class='uk-form'>
                                        <input type='hidden' name='id_pasaran' value='<?php echo $b['id_pasaran']; ?>'/>
                                        <select name='status_pasaran' class='uk-form-small'>
                                            <option <?php if($b['status_pasaran']=='Offline') echo 'selected'; ?> >Offline</option>
                                            <option <?php if($b['status_pasaran']=='Online') echo 'selected'; ?> >Online</option>
                                        </select>
                                        <button class='uk-button uk-button-primary uk-button-small'>Update</button>
                                    </form>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

I try to add this script

```
<form action='<?php echo base_url('home/update_pasaran'); ?>' method='POST' class='uk-form'>
                                        <input type='hidden' name='id_pasaran' value='<?php echo $b['id_pasaran']; ?>'/>
                                        <select name='status_pasaran' class='uk-form-small'>
                                            <option <?php if($b['status_pasaran']=='Offline') echo 'selected'; ?> >Offline</option>
                                            <option <?php if($b['status_pasaran']=='Online') echo 'selected'; ?> >Online</option>
                                        </select>
                                        <button class='uk-button uk-button-primary uk-button-small'>Update</button>
                                    </form>
```

but the only one updated when I click the button is the last row.

can someone guide me?

Comment: sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1):

This is how your code should look like in the clientside

```
            <div class='tableContainer'>
                <form action='post.php' method='POST' class='uk-form'>
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <th width='100px'>Pasaran</th>                          
                            <th width='150px'>Status</th>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <?php foreach($pasaran as $b){ ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td width='101px'><?php echo $b['keterangan']; ?></td>
                                <td width='151px'>
                                    <?php if($b['status_pasaran']=='Offline'){?>
                                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="Online[]" value="DB_ID"></td>
                                    <?php } else{ ?>
                                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="Offline[]" value="DB_ID"></td>
                                    <?php }?>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <input type="submit" value="APPLY CHANGES">
                </form>
            </div>
```

The file post.php should be something like this:

```
$online_array = $_POST["Online"];
$offline_array = $_POST["Offline"];

if(isset($online_array)&&!empty($online_array)){
    foreach($online_array as $object_to_update){
        /*Your query for the data base goes here*/

    }
}

if(isset($offline_array)&&!empty($offline_array)){
    foreach($offline_array as $object_to_update){
        /*Your query for the data base goes here*/

    }
```

}

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. can you please explain more? why do you use "checkbox"?

Comment: The checkbox will be in each table row and if this is selected it is send to the server as an array.

Comment: I just want to create 1 more button to change the status to "online" or "offline" for all

Comment: I see, I change the answer, hope this fit your needs

Comment: thank you abner. i changed the checkbox with option and put the form outside the table but it's still not working except the last option box for the last row... now i have multiple option box and 1 update button. can you guide me again?

Comment: The code has been updated Rebeca, hope this fits your needs

Comment: Abner, I tried your script last night but when i click the submit button now nothing changed, not even the last row.

Comment: In your PHP code please insert the following code at the beggining of your head print_r($_POST), copy paste the results in the comment